# Why was this question closed as needing details or clarity when it didn't fit the close reason examples?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, closed-questions, reopen-closed

I recently created a Q&A style question for replacing a single page within a PDF using the Imgagemagick tool ([How can I replace a single PDF page using Imagemagick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64724126/how-can-i-replace-a-single-pdf-page-using-imagemagick/64724127)).  I created the question since it's similar to things I've wanted to achieve in the past, and while I've found portions of the answer scattered online, I didn't see a cohesive solution posted anywhere (including on Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange).

I can see where my [initial revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/64724126/1) of the question could have used some improvement (I hadn't documented any commands I used in my attempts thus far or why they didn't meet my goal), and have since improved it in that regard.  However, this still doesn't quite fit the examples mentioned in the [linked description of](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) "Needs details or clarity":

> - **Needs details or clarity** - sometimes we need more information in order to help solve your problem.
>
> > This question should include more details and clarify the problem.
> > Edit your post to be more specific about what you're looking for, and be sure to address any concerns that other users brought up in the comments.

From what I can see, my initial question included everything asked for in the above.  It specifically stated the exact problem attempting to be solved, and the rationale for it.  No users had brought up any concerns in the comments, so there was nothing to address on that front.  And all the information needed to solve the problem was in the text.

Is this a case where the description of the close reason is incomplete?  i.e. you can't list every possible edge case for a close reason, but it fits the general umbrella?  Was this closed for the wrong reason?  Was this the best close reason, but none of them really fit?  Or should this have ideally not been closed?

And I guess finally, does my edit to the post sufficiently address the close reason, or is there something else I'm missing?  I see nothing else in the close reason description to guide me to a solution, but perhaps there's something elsewhere in Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange about question asking that I'm missing.

Comment: It does not look like programming question... The linked question would definitely benefit from some editing to clarify how it is related to writing code to manipulate PDFs vs. "find a tool/give me command line options for common tool" the way it looks now. Both "need more details" and "make it more narrow" (as well as custom write-in reason) could be used  to close in my opinion.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Which implies that the "needs details or clarity" close reason didn't fit, got it.

Comment: If it is off-topic for Stack Overflow, is there a more on-topic Stack Exchange site?  Nothing leapt out on me.

Comment: Super User, maybe.

Comment: I guess that "needs details" it's because it's not clear you are **not** asking a programming question? Maybe there is a programming issue there that you forgot to make clear? When you ask about the wrong topic in the wrong site, sometimes it can be seen as "unclear", particularly if it looks like it _could_ be on-topic if some details were added.

Comment: @yivi how far can you stretch the reasoning for a wrong close reason before it becomes funny?

Comment: I have no idea what happened, I remember flagging this and checked my log and sure enough it wasnt for clarity: ` Not suitable for this site – Fabián Heredia Montiel Nov 7 at 3:24   helpful `. I also remember not downvoting it hoping it would be migrated to superuser.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It does not look like a programming question at this point...

The [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64724126/how-can-i-replace-a-single-pdf-page-using-imagemagick) would definitely benefit from some editing to clarify how it is related to writing code to manipulate PDF files vs. "find a tool/give me command line options for common tool" the way it looks now.

Generally off-topic questions should be closed and while ideally the close reason should match the question, it is not always easy, so a somewhat arbitrary reason is used.

In this particular case the following reasons could have been used:

- Needs details or clarity - maybe it is a programming question, and some edit may clarify how it is.
- Needs more focus -  what exact problem you have, what language you need to use - so many choices
- About general computing hardware and software - that looks the most appropriate one to me as it has the most likely recommendation, but not a migration to my understanding.
- Other - add a comment - someone could write out a more specific explanation... It can easily end up being somewhat rude, so it is unlikely to be used on such a question.
- belongs on superuser.com - that is migration. Only use it when you know it is on-topic on the target site. Since the question was closed by a moderator I'd assume they knew the question in the current state is unlikely to be on-topic on Super User (but also they could have decided that investigating whether it is on-topic there for a self-answered question is not worth the trouble)

Comment: The "needs details or clarity" example feels like a stretch, especially when you compare it to the description of the close reason.  It feels like it's intended to be used when the question can't be answered due to missing information, not for when it's unclear whether it's a fit for the site.

Comment: @M.Justin And what close reason would you use when it's not clear if it's a fit for the site or not?

Comment: @yivi "Off-topic" fits that perfectly.

Comment: @M.Justin "Off-topic" includes half a dozen different options (well, actually it doesn't exist at all any more, but I'm assuming you're referring to the option that used to be called that). Which of those would you choose? Or do you think a custom reason is necessary?

Comment: @M.Justin I think that if you can't really tell if it's on-topic or not, saying "it needs details or clarity" it's perfectly appropriate choice.

Answer (score -11):

This was closed with the wrong close reason, there was nothing unclear about the question, and ImageMagick is a command line tool for image manipulation, used mainly from within programming and scripting languages. Questions about its usage are as on-topic as are questions about ffmpeg and Git.

Reopened.

Comment: Does this mean that this question would be on-topic for both Stack Overflow and Super User?

Comment: From [tag:ffmpeg]'s tag wiki: "Questions about interactive use of the command line tool should be asked on Super User or Video Production." The question doesn't *seem* to be about using it in a programming context, but maybe I'm missing something - thus the discussion under Alexei's answer.

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. The question and answer apply to command line use as well as use from, say, a PHP wrapper. The close reason doesn't apply at all either way, so I chose to overrule it.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery The same is not on the [imagemagick](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/imagemagick/info) tag.  Presumably they should be consistent in this regard.

Comment: @CodeCaster By that logic, any question about those tools is theoretically on-topic, so that part of the tag wiki is meaningless.

Comment: @John exactly. Perhaps the ffmpeg tag people got fed up with the "how to convert video format X to Y" questions, and until that happens to ImageMagick as well, we shouldn't prevent useful information about a tool commonly used by programmers to be shared on this site.

Comment: @CodeCaster, title is ok, but the question is specifically request for library (off-topic by definition): *"with ImageMagick (or alternatively, some other tool)"*. I'd vote-close it myself. What makes it worse is self-answer, which boils down to knowing command line parameters /facepalm. Imagine thousands of posts with answers like this (varios combinations of command switches and input parameters), are they really belong to SO? Nope.

Comment: While I strongly agree your answer, I believe it would not be a problem to narrow the SO topicality, if there would be a way to migrate the offtopic questions to a better matching site. This can not happen because the company looks always for more important problems.

Comment: @Sinatr why not, are they standing in the way of something? I kind of consider it to be extended documentation. Look at the tens of thousands of Git questions like _"How can I move the last [1, 2, ... N] commits to another branch?"_, which are answered over and over again, and upvoted. They're on-topic and helpful to some. I do agree with the title part, but that's easily edited out.

Comment: @CodeCaster, command switch questions by default go to super user. Git, msbuild and such are somewhat exceptions, since having expertise in them is unlikely for non-programmers and they have direct connection with programming environment. ImageMagick (and other processing tools) can be used by non-programmers and have 0 relationship to a certain language. The question of OP is not language-agnostic, it has nothing to do with programming at all.

Comment: @Sinatr Just edited it to remove the "(or alternatively, some other tool)" part.  It was just a tangential comment added since I noticed a bunch of the existing PDF questions for ImageMagick had answers that were basically "Don't do that, use X instead".  It's not really core to my question.

Comment: **ALWAYS edit the question** and **NEVER post a new one**. If you post a new one you are vulnerable to downvotes for deleting a question and or for posting a duplicate question. I tried posting a new one and ended up with 4 downvotes in the process.